# What is this jet seen in the Falcon Crest TV series?

Tags: aircraft-identification, jet

[image]

This is another jetliner from "Falcon Crest" I'm trying to identify.  It was visible briefly in episode # 194 <8.11> "True Confessions" (1989).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that it is an [Israeli Aircraft Industries Westwind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAI_Westwind). This is based on the mid-set wing and the 5 windows on each side.

[image: image of plane]

Image source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/IAI_Westwind_%282323424886%29.jpg/300px-IAI_Westwind_%282323424886%29.jpg

Comment: Thank you so much!